# How to access slot props from the component used inside the slot?

Tags: vue.js

so everything i can find about scoped slots and passing props dont work for my specific situation:

i have following component order:

Home/List/ListItem

now i desided to replace the ListItem with a slot and because i use the List in a other Component too, but in there i need the ListOptionsItem.

in my home component i did this:

```
               <list 
                class="mapkeyList"
                :content="displayList"
                :filterbar="true"
                @handleSelection="addSelection"
                @delete="deleteElement"
                @editItem="editItem"
                header="Mapkeys"
                :key="mapkeyListKey"
           >
                <list-item>
                </list-item>
           </list>
```

in my List component i have this:

```
<template>
 <div>
      <h2 v-if="header">{{header}}</h2>
      <div  class="listContainer"  v-if="showedContent.length > 0">
           
           <div v-for=" (item, index) in showedContent" :key="index">
                <slot 
                     :item="item"
                     :index="index"
                     :dragable="dragableItems"
                     @auswahl="auswahlHandle"
                     @deleteElement="deleteElement"
                     @editItem="editItem"
                     :dontShowButtons="dontShowButtons"
                     @dragStart="handleOverDragStart"
                     :dragItem="dragItem"
                     @position="$emit('emitPosition',item)"
                     :deaktivierbar="deaktivierbar"
                >
                </slot >
           </div>
```

finaly the listItem and the listOptionsItem need to access this props in the slot:

listItem:

```
<template>
 <div class= "flexSpaceBetween" @click="$emit('auswahl',item)">
      <div class="textFett">
           {{item[0]}}
      </div>
      <div>
           {{item[1]}}
      </div>
 </div>
```

i dont want to write all the neccessarry code in the home component because the listOptionsItem does need more informations and more space to write code.

my goal was it to define in the Home component that i want the list to use the listItem component and in the Options component the list should use the listItemOptions component. in the future there could be added new listItem versions.

Comment: It is really not clear what you want. What exactly do you mean by *i cant get it to work without blowing my home component up like a baloon* ?

Comment: i want to accsess the properties in the child component and not in the home component.

Comment: well then you must pass it down via props....

Comment: you cant. thats my problem.
You see in the second code sniped that i pass ":item='item'". but the child dosnt have accsess

Comment: No, you are making the `item` available to the **slot**, not to the component used inside the slot...

Comment: ok. but the props that i have to pass to the component are in the list component. but the listItem will be inserted at the home component level. the home component does not have accsess to this props. you see it in the snipeds: in the home component i iniziate the list component and fill the slot with the listItem. the second sniped showes the slot inside the List thats reseaved the item. and the thirt is the item by itself. i cant get the twist between this three components to share the props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any component used inside [scoped slot](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#scoped-slots) has no implicit access to the slot props. To make them available **inside** the component, you must pass it down to that component as props explicitly...

```html
<list 
  class="mapkeyList"
  :content="displayList"
  :key="mapkeyListKey">
  <template v-slot:default="{ item }">
    <list-item :item="item">
    </list-item>
  </template>
</list>
```

If you have a lot of props/events you want to pass along, the ability of both [v-bind](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#passing-the-properties-of-an-object) and [v-on](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-on) to take an object as an argument is very useful because you can pass all the data and event handlers at the same time:

```js
// List component
<template>
<div>
  <h2 v-if="header">{{header}}</h2>
  <div  class="listContainer"  v-if="showedContent.length > 0">
        
    <div v-for=" (item, index) in showedContent" :key="index">
       <slot :props="slotProps" :on="slotEventsHandlers"
       </slot >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    slotProps() {
      return {
        item: this.item,
        dragable: this.dragableItems
      }
    },
    slotEventsHandlers() {
      return {
        deleteElement: this.deleteElement,
        dragStart: this.handleOverDragStart
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And use it in parent:

```html
<list 
  class="mapkeyList"
  :content="displayList"
  :key="mapkeyListKey">
  <template v-slot:default="{ props, on }">
    <list-item v-bind="props" v-on="on">
    </list-item>
  </template>
</list>
```

Comment: that didnt work because the sniped you showed is located in the Home-component. Home-component dosn't know about item. item will be created in the list-component itself inside a for-loop.

Comment: Yes `item` is inside list component, but it is made available to the slot (e.g. parent component that uses the list component) - so you can use `item` **inside** the slot template!

Comment: thank you for you patience. i dont quite understand this solution, but i dig into it. as what i can tell now is: it works! thank you!

Comment: Just read the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#scoped-slots) carefully ...it explains the concept very well